# Disable Administrator account on Windows 7 Starter Edition

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, administrator

How can I disable the Administrator account on Windows 7 Starter Edition?  I enabled it using the NT Password and Registry Editor so that I could install software for a client who didn't leave me their netbook password.  There doesn't appear to be a way to disable it using Windows itself (no lusrmgr.msc, `net user Administrator /enable:no` gives an error, no secpol.msc).

Comment: The tool doesn't allow me to disable, just to enable.  I'm trying to disable it from an administrator account but I can't see any way to do that in Starter Edition.

Comment: Isn't it enough to just give the Administrator account a password that the client doesn't know?

Comment: There's no way that I can see to change the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by loading the SAM registry hive and editing the `Domains\Account\Users\000001F4\F` value and setting the 38th byte to 11.  11 is disabled 10 is enabled.

I used the NT Password and Offline Registry Editor http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/regedit.txt to do this.  Once you `cd` to the right key, the commands to edit are as follows:

```
ed 000001F4
d      <to print>
:38    <enter 11>
d      <to print>
s
quit
```