# Remove 'Administrator' account Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator

I have trouble removing the administrator account from my notebook. It was created when I wanted to access some read-only files and I wrote "net user administrator active" in cmd. (didnt work out tho) I tried removing it but there is not an option to do so. The delete account button is not available in user settings and I can not remove it from the settings menu. It seems that its not a real account but when I turn the notebook on I have the option to sign into that account.
Any ideas?
thx

Comment: It is not possible to delete this account.  You can only disable it.  My answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1024203/how-to-get-rights-of-admin-after-i-disabled-all-admin-accounts-in-my-computer/1024221#1024221) explains how you enable it. Step 10 in that answer explains that if you change the `11` to `10` you enable the account.  In this case you would do the same procedure but change the `10` to `11` and that would disable the account.  Since the procedure is identical except for that step I refuse to duplicate my answer and instead will flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: The process described in the existing answer to, [Disable Administrator account on Windows 7 Starter Edition](https://superuser.com/questions/543364/disable-administrator-account-on-windows-7-starter-edition), is identical on Windows 10.

Comment: The answer to, [How do I disable administrator prompt in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/464758/how-do-i-disable-administrator-prompt-in-windows-8), also applies to Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Click start button->type in 'run' without quotes, then type in: lusrmgr.msc 
this open a nice snap-in. Now go to the "Users" folder on the left hand-side and all the local users will show-up. From there, you may opt out to disable the account

Comment: As noted in the question comments you can't delete the built-in Administrator, only disabled it.

Comment: though edited earlier, i edited it again. thnx